# How to compile and host asp.net websites?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to understand the basics of deploying a c#.net website on a Godaddy server.
As of now, project runs properly when I press F5 in Visual Web Developper 2010. However, when I upload it I get the error: constants does not exist in the current context. constants is defined in the file constants.cs which is located in the same directory.

I'm not familiar with c#.net, so here are my questionments

- Do I need some kind of includes to reference constants.cs?
- Do I need to build the website a special way?
- Is there a folder structure that I need to follow?

Comment: If all are in the same project, just copying the output DLL file into the `bin` directory should work. Did you copy the DLL file(s) into the `bin` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

•Do I need some kind of includes to reference constants.cs?

Depends. Normally yes, but hey, you dont tell us anything about how your project is installed. In general, you upload all code files that are in app_code.

•Do I need to build the website a special way?

No, they basically get built on the server (as in: copiled) when you just upload them.

•Is there a folder structure that I need to follow?

Only the standard ASp.NET structure (as documented in... the documentation) with /bin, /app_code etc. and any modifications your hoster demands. In general, no.

Just upload all files.

Answer (score 1):

It could depend on whether you are using Web site or Web application project type (http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/06/ASPNET-Web-Site-versus-Web-Application-Project.aspx). "[Web deployment project](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19995)" functionality can ease this process if you are using Web application projects.